# Parsing Website with JavaScript enabled Content

Tags: c#, webclient

I want to download all pictures from this [website](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18827/places-landscapes-wallpaper). Basically, I want to parse the `results` string, for links to .jpg and download those files. However, the code I got returns an html string, that doesn't have any links to jpgs at all in it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetBackgrounds
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18827/places-landscapes-wallpaper";


            string results;

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)";
                results = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since the html-preview in visual studio shows an error, saying JavaScript disabled, I guess it has something to do with that?

Comment: You need a browser component because the javascript needs to run to populate the DOM. Look into [Chromium](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx) or check if the WebBrowser on a winforms/WPF window suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into that